# What is a word for "loudly whispered"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> "Don't make a sound!" he _______ed, trying to be as loud as he could without being too noticeable.

Comment: If the whispered statement is intended to be overheard, then it's a *stage whisper*.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps "hissed" would be a good choice.

To ***[hiss](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hiss):***

> - to say (something) in a loud or angry whisper.

(Merriam-Webster)